# web view doesn't show all data

Tags: java, android, webview

I get content of a page with api.
but It doesn't show all content.

```
Log.e("content",newsDetailModel.getFullContent()); //it shows all data
WebSettings settings = news_details_content.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
news_details_content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
           
String content = newsDetailModel.getFullContent();
news_details_content.loadData(content, "text/html", "utf8");
```

my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_details_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
  

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/news_details_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ca please add your full layout file here?

Comment: @DHAVALA. added full layout.

Answer (score 0):

Got your issue.

It is because you have used `wrap_content` height for your ImageView.
It means if your image has high resolution it'll consume almost everything on screen. And will draw your webview outside the screen.

So I suggest you make the height of ImageView fixed.
Replace your layout file code with the below code. It'll solve your issue. You can adjust the height for ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_details_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/news_details_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```